# Popover from a CGPoint

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad

How to display a prepared popover (TableView inside) with the arrow on a specific point? Basically, I have a CGPoint screenPointContainer and I want to show my popover there. No rectangles, no buttons.
Just a single point.

```
detailsPop.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 300);
CGRect myrect = CGRectMake(screenPointContainer.x, screenPointContainer.y, ??, ??);
[detailsPop presentPopoverFromRect:myrect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the reason of that coordinate distortion (60 units upper) and had to manually edit the coordinates, including orientation checks. Rectangle's H and W are both 0.
Now it is OK:

```
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ==  UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{

        CGRect myrect2 = CGRectMake(screenPointContainer.x+320, screenPointContainer.y+60, 0, 0);
        [detailsPop presentPopoverFromRect:myrect2 inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

} else {

        CGRect myrect2 = CGRectMake(screenPointContainer.x, screenPointContainer.y+60, 0, 0);
        [detailsPop presentPopoverFromRect:myrect2 inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just create a CGRect with a 1 pixel size? Which would basically be a point:

`CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(screenPointContainer.x, screenPointContainer.y, 1, 1);`

Comment: In this case the popover spawns higher than the actual point of clicking.